# Objective-C: NSTimer selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timer

Is it possible to initiate a timer and pass the selector method with multiple arguments?

Below is a simple example of a working timer:

```
gameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(gameLoop:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
```

The selector method would be named `- (void)gameLoop:(NSTimer *)theTimer;`

Is it possible to pass this selector method with multiple arguments? So that the `gameLoop` method could also deal with an `int` value and a `bool` value?

The following obviously doesn't work, but might highlight what I'm after:

```
gameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(gameLoop:NO:75)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];

- (void)gameLoop:(NSTimer *)theTimer isRunning:(bool)running numberOfSteps:(int)steps;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I disagree with BOTH answers.  Of course you can pass whatever *info* you want to the method your NSTimer calls. That's what the

```
userInfo
```

parameter is for!

```
NSNumber *steps = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 75];   

NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: steps forKey: @"steps"];
//Pass any objects in a dictionary for easy extraction.
gameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(gameLoop:)
                                       userInfo: info
                                        repeats:YES];
```

Now you can extract the userInfo in the selector.

```
- (void)gameLoop:(NSTimer *)theTimer{
    NSDictionary info = [theTimer userInfo];
    NSInteger steps = [[info valueForKey: @"steps"] integerValue];
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: You can't use `NSInteger` as an object, you have to use `NSNumber` instead if you want to put it into a dictionary.

Comment: fixed. fast typing and not thinking.

Answer (score 0):

No.

From the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:

> *aSelector*
>
> The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must have the following signature:
>
> ```
> - (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
> ```
>
> The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.

Could workaround with something like...

```
- (void)gameLoopA:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    [self gameLoop:theTimer isRunning:NO numberOfSteps:75];
}

- (void)gameLoopB:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    [self gameLoop:theTimer isRunning:NO numberOfSteps:50];
}

// etc, etc.
```